# Setting EdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeAll and Nav Bar translucent:NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uivewcontroller

Is there a way to set `EdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeAll` and Nav Bar `translucent:NO` at the same time.

Right now, when I set `EdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeAll` for my view controller and my `navigationBar.translucent = NO`, the view starts after the navigation bar. I need a way to start my view from (0,0) and also to set the translucent property to NO.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting EdgesForExtendedLayout to "UIRectEdgeNone".